# PhantomJS access internal server without TLD via Selenium

Tags: r, selenium, phantomjs

I'm working on an internal webscraper at my company to pull names and IDs from a Sharepoint list.  Let's assume that this is the only way I can access the information.  From R, I'm using RSelenium to control phantomJS (I've successfully connected to external servers and pulled in data so I know it's working in general).  When I navigate to the site `http://teams4/AllItems.aspx` phantom decides to be helpful and change the URL to `teams4.com`.  Now, I'm using cntlm as a local authentication proxy before the big corporate proxy (it lets Python and R connect to the Internet) - without it I couldn't get to the internet at all.  I tried connecting directly the corporate   Is there a way to force phantom to resolve the name the way it's given?

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

beautifulSoup = function(source){
  s = source %>% 
    extract2(1) %>% 
    html()
  return(s)
}

pJS = phantom(pjs_cmd="C:/phantomjs2/bin/phantomjs.exe",extras="--proxy=localhost:3128")
remDr = remoteDriver(browserName = 'phantomjs')
remDr$open()

output = data.frame(Name="test",ID=0)

remDr$navigate('http://teams4/AllItems.aspx')
soup = beautifulSoup(remDr$getPageSource())
allRequestors = soup %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//td[contains(@class,"ms-vb-user")]')
```

Comment: Have you tried PhantomJS 2? A possible workaround can be simply using the IP.

Comment: I am using PhantomJS 2 (just downloaded it today).  I've tried using tracert to get the IP but when I enter that IP, I don't end up at the site I anticipated.